# unit-test tooltip visibility and content

Tags: jsf, if-statement, title

Consider the following situation:

I got a title which is either 'A' when the type of an object is 'someType', or is empty apart from that. That is:

```
title="#{type eq 'someType' ? 'A' : ''}"
```

If the string returned by type changes, I won't get any errors. To be precise, the tooltip will be visible no longer, whilst I get no warnings on this. The important thing is, that type is not in my responsibility, but instead in another project. I defined an enum to use this in my code, which represents the values that type can receive.

```
public enum Type {

    SOME_TYPE("someType"), //
    ANOTHER_TYPE("anotherType");

    String descr;

    private Types(String descr) {
        this.descr= descr;
    }

}
```

Do you have any best practices here?

Comment: I edited my initial post. type is actually something like 'product.something', which is a string itself. The problem is, that this product is from another project i am dependent of. I can't access the code in there. The strings 'someType' and 'anotherType' are deep inside the external product. This enum however is made by me and thus accessable.

Comment: The problem is, that this is not safe to refactorings. Think of product.something returns 'renamedType' instead of 'someType'. I won't get any errors then, but the tooltip won't be visible any longer.

Comment: As mentioned in my second comment, I can't change the return type of #{type}, as it is not under my control.

Comment: Is my problem clear to everyone?

Comment: Well, it would work if I could use the enum in the jsf page. Then I could use the description of SOME_TYPE, instead of the hard coded "someType". This would be test-covered as well, because i got an unit test, that tests whether the string matches the one of the project i am dependant of, or not.